# Induction to show that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is not ordered

Tags: proof-verification, induction, finite-fields, ordered-fields

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Given a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p = \{1,2,...,p-1\}$ with $p$ elements and $p$ is prime, defined as follows: both addition and multiplication are defined as the remainder of the outcome when divided by $p$. Prove that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is not ordered.

I'm specifically curious if induction would work by first considering $\Bbb{F}_p$ is ordered => there exists $P$ s.t. for all $x \in \Bbb{F}_p$ one of the following is true: $x = 0$, $x \in P$, or $-x \in P$. And $x,y \in P  \Rightarrow x+y, xy \in P$

consider $1 \in \Bbb{F}_p$. Either $1$ or $-1$ is in $P$.

if $1$ is in $P$ then $1+1$ is also in $P$, and $1+1+1$, etc... until every element of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is in $P$ which would then force a contradiction $b/c$ if every value of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is in $P$ then for any given element, $z$, there are no value in $\Bbb{F}_p$ remaining to be $-z$.

If $-1$ is in $\Bbb{F}_p$, then $-1 = p - 1$, and I can do pretty much the exact same process as above $p-1$ is in $P$ => $(p-1) + (p-1) = p-2$ is in $P$, etc...

This obviously makes me want to induct, however I was pretty certain I could only do induction on a finite set if it's also well founded, and I can't find an R-minimal element in any subset of $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: You can certainly use induction to show that if $x\in P$, then $mx\in P$ for all positive integers $m$. Then you run into the contradiction (for any $x\neq0$)  the usual way as $-x=(p-1)x$ is then also in $P$. In other words, the induction will be on that multiplier $m$, which you can think of as a natural number. And the set of natural numbers is surely well founded for the purposes of induction.

Comment: Personally i'd just go for that no field with a sum of non-zero squares equalling 0 or -1 can be ordered

Answer (score 3):

What does it mean to be ordered?  Any nonzero characteristic is incompatible with being ordered, because $x+x+\ldots x = 0$.

Comment: Our definition of ordered was: F is ordered if there exists subset P of F s.t. I) for all x in F exactly one of the following is true: x = 0, x is in P, -x is in P II) x,y in P => x+y, x*y in P. This is a very base level theorem assuming no knowledge. That certainly is a much nicer/easier way to show that it's ordered.

Comment: So if $x \in P$, $0 = x+\ldots + x$ (with $p$ $x$'s) $\in P$.